# (Rather simple) tensor computation

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, field-theory

I have two short questions in the steps of doing Lorentz transformations with angular momentum.

First, the infinitesimal form of the Lorentz transform is set up as $\Lambda^{\mu}_{\nu} = \delta^{\mu}_{\nu} + w^{\mu}_{\nu}$, where $w^{\mu}_{\nu}$ is infinitesimal. I understand up to the part where the condition which makes $\Lambda$ a Lorentz transformation would be
$$(\delta^{\mu}_{\sigma} + w^{\mu}_{\sigma})(\delta^{\nu}_{\tau} + w^{\nu}_{\tau})\eta^{\sigma\tau} = \eta^{\mu\nu}.$$

However, I am having a trouble getting how the condition $ w^{\mu \nu}+w^{\nu \mu} = 0$ would ensure the above equations to hold.

After a few steps away, I understood up to the part $\delta L = -w^{\mu}_{\nu} x^{\nu} \partial_{\mu}L$, where $L$ is a Lagrangian density.

But I am not exactly understanding how the fact that $w^{\mu}_{\mu} = 0$ due to the antisymmetry makes $-w^{\mu}_{\nu} x^{\nu} \partial_{\mu}L = -\partial_{\mu}(w^{\mu}_{\nu}x^{\nu}L)$.

Comment: Regarding the first part, I think you can work it out if you remember that $ w^{\mu \nu} = w^{\mu}_\sigma \eta^{\sigma \nu}$. Regarding the second part, maybe you should give more context and details, I'm not really getting the question.

Comment: I just noticed that maybe [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/135277/the-variation-of-the-lagrangian-density-under-an-infinitesimal-lorentz-transform?rq=1) answers the second part of your question

Comment: For the second part, use the chain rule to develop the RHS, keeping in mind that $w_\nu^\mu$ does not depend on $x$.

Answer (score 0):

First, $\partial_\mu \Lambda^\mu_\nu = 0$ since the $\Lambda^\mu_\nu$s are just numbers. This implies $\partial_\mu w^\mu_\nu = 0$. Then, you just have to compute $\partial_\mu(w^\mu_\nu x^\nu L) = w^\mu_\nu (\partial_\mu x^\nu) L + w^\mu_\nu x^\nu (\partial_\mu L)$. The first term may be rewritten $w^\mu_\nu \delta^\nu_\mu$, which vanishes.